# Getting and setting `client_id` & `session_id` from GA4 when used through GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

While trying to set up [Cross-Domain Tracking](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10071811?hl=en), I followed this guide, but our sites are a little too complex for GA4 automatic tagging to handle. Even though I have managed to retain the `_gl` query parameter all the way to the other site, there are still scenarios where Cross-Domain Tracking doesn't function correctly; probably because of a need to add the parameter after a session started, in some cases.

All that is to say I now want to try [the manual approach](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10071811?hl=en#zippy=%2Cmanual-setup), which involves getting the `client_id` and `session_id` and passing them to the other site, then setting them manually there. However, we are using GTM, and the suggested approach in the docs doesn't seem to work in this case because the global `gtag` object is not available.

How can I get and set the `client_id` and `session_id` from GA4 implemented through GTM?

Answer (score 0):

While there is no documentation explicitly for this scenario, nor any that states you don't get `gtag` when using the standard snippet, I did discover a solution [squirrelled away in some unrelated documentation](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/datalayer). The `gtag` referred to in other documentation is just a function that directly passes its arguments to the `push` function of the `dataLayer`.

```js
function gtag() {
  window.dataLayer.push(arguments);
}
```

Now we can use this for all the other documented functionality of `gtag`.

```js
gtag("get", MEASUREMENT_ID, "client_id", (v) => console.log(v));
```